# Converting trained Tensorflow model to protobuf

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

The inception net in the [Android Tensorflow Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) stores the model as a protobuf file ([tensorflow_inception_graph.pb](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip)). I'd like to replace this network with another one.

Is there documentation or an example somewhere on how to convert a trained TensorFlow network in Python to `.pb`? I'm aware of TensorFlow's [Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) but this seems to be used to save intermediate training state. Not sure how it works if the model is already trained.

Comment: if one of the mentioned answers is correct or you found a different solution and update here would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.Graph.as_graph_def()` retrieves the serialized graph. Then you just write it to a file.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of [saving](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/00440e99ffb1ed1cfe4b4ea650e0c560838a6edc/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph_test.py#L68) and [loading](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/00440e99ffb1ed1cfe4b4ea650e0c560838a6edc/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph_test.py#L79)