# How to keep tensorflow session open between predictions? Loading from SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a tensorflow model that i'd like to run predictions on from numpy arrays. This is for image processing within videos. I will pass the images to the model as they happen. Not every frame is passed.

I [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667018/locally-load-saved-tensorflow-model-pb-from-google-cloud-machine-learning-engin) my SavedModel within a session like so

```
def run(self):                
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,
                    [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
```

My code works perfectly if I pass a list of images (self.tfimages) to the prediction. Condensed to:

```
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_ops/softmax:0')
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Placeholder:0': self.tfimages})
```

But i won't have all the images at once. Do I really have to reload the model from file each time (takes 2+ minutes).

I thought to do something like this

```
class tensorflow_model:
def __init__(self):                
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as self.sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(self.sess,
                    [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
def predict(self):

        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = self.sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_ops/softmax:0')

        predictions = self.sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Placeholder:0': self.tfimages})
```

but that yields

builtins.RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session

Is there a way to keep a session open, or perhaps load SavedModel independent of a session?

EDIT
I tried the first answer to create a session in two steps:

```
sess=tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
sess
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x0000021ACBB62EF0>
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Debug Probe, prompt 138, line 1
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 222, in load
    saver.restore(sess, variables_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1428, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 774, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
builtins.RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

Whereas

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
```

executes without error.

As for the second idea of passing sess as a variable to class, which is a good one. This works:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
    tensorflow_instance=tensorflow(read_from="file")
    tensorflow_instance.predict(sess)
```

But this doesn't

```
sess=tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
tensorflow_instance=tensorflow(read_from="file")
tensorflow_instance.predict(sess)
```

It would be pretty awkward to wrap my program into the with as sess statement.

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2
import os
import glob

class tensorflow:    

def __init__(self,read_from):

    #frames to be analyzed
    self.tfimages=[]    

    find_photos=glob.glob("*.jpg")

    # Read in the image_data
    if read_from=="file":
        for x in find_photos:
            image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(x, 'rb').read()    
            self.tfimages.append(image_data)

    # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
    self.label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile("dict.txt")]

def predict(self,sess):

    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_ops/softmax:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Placeholder:0': self.tfimages})
    for prediction in predictions:
        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = prediction.argsort()[-len(prediction):][::-1]

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = self.label_lines[node_id]
            score = prediction[node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
        return(human_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
        tensorflow_instance=tensorflow(read_from="file")
        tensorflow_instance.predict(sess)

    sess=tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
    tensorflow_instance=tensorflow(read_from="file")
    tensorflow_instance.predict(sess)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Others have explained why you can't put your session in a `with` statement in the constructor.

The reason you see different behavior when using the context manager vs. not is because `tf.saved_model.loader.load` has some weird interactions between the default graph and the graph that is part of the session.

The solution is simple; don't pass a graph to session if you're not using it in a `with` block:

```
sess=tf.Session()
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
```

Here's some example code for a class to do predictions:

```
class Model(object):

  def __init__(self, model_path):
    # Note, if you don't want to leak this, you'll want to turn Model into
    # a context manager. In practice, you probably don't have to worry
    # about it.
    self.session = tf.Session()

    tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        self.session,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        model_path)

    self.softmax_tensor = self.session.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_ops/softmax:0')

  def predict(self, images):
    predictions = self.session.run(self.softmax, {'Placeholder:0': images})
    # TODO: convert to human-friendly labels
    return predictions


images = [tf.gfile.FastGFile(f, 'rb').read() for f in glob.glob("*.jpg")]
model = Model('model_path')
print(model.predict(images))

# Alternatively (uses less memory, but has lower throughput):
for f in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
  print(model.predict([tf.gfile.FastGFile(f, 'rb').read()]))
```

Comment: Wait Serving comes built into Tensorflow? Why was I building it

Comment: Checkout the answer below about tensorflow_serving as well as https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/saved_model_predictor.py

Comment: FWIW -- I had to call `sess.__enter__()` to start the session in the Model class. Remember that `with` will do this and you need the context manager for a TF session.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a scope which is exited after it leaves init.

```
def __init__(self): 
  with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as self.sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(self.sess[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
```

The following should work for you if you have everything else working properly.

```
def __init__(self):   
  self.sess=tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(self.sess[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], "model")
```

When I do something like this I also usually create the option of passing the session to the class by a parameter, then when I call the class I pass in a session create by `with`

Comment: not quite. edited above. returns "builtins.RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()."

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because in your init function you open the session and close it. So there is no session after init finishes.

If you want to make many predictions after your model has been trained, I recommend you not to reinvent the wheel and use the tool, TF developers created for this reason: [TF serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/).

> TensorFlow Serving is a flexible, high-performance serving system for
>   machine learning models, designed for production environments.
>   TensorFlow Serving makes it easy to deploy new algorithms and
>   experiments, while keeping the same server architecture and APIs.
>   TensorFlow Serving provides out-of-the-box integration with TensorFlow
>   models, but can be easily extended to serve other types of models and
>   data

They have a lot of tutorials starting from the [very basic ones](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) and spending a day on learning a few things will save you months later.

Comment: While I agree that the user shouldn't try to rewrite a serving system, it doesn't seem like the OP necessarily wants a serving system, just a simple way to get some predictions out of a model using a familiar/simple language. Performance should be more than adequate since numpy arrays and session.run are all C++ code anyways.

Comment: @rhaertel80 there is nothing wrong with your answer, just wanted to tell that there is no need to reinvent the wheel. The problem was solved before and all that is needed now it to familiarize yourself with a solution. The language will be still familiar because this is the same python.

Comment: TF Serving includes C++ libraries for inference along with gRPC servers build on those libraries. Agreed that if the goal is serving and/or C++ inference, TF Serving is the tool of choice. I do think there should be a more convenient Python solution for non-serving cases, although, as you can see, it's only about 5 lines of code. FWIW, TF Serving authors were the ones that provided the tf.saved_model.load and related functions.