# Is there a way to load tensorflow model only once in server instead of loading the model every time with a new incoming request?

Tags: tensorflow, deployment

I have created a model by transfer learning with the object detection API of TensorFlow. This particular model is deployed in a flask server where the request is coming from an android app.

My code is working completely fine and I am able to achieve the desired result. But the only thing is the latency. For every request made from the android app with the test image, **it is taking almost 30s to get the output.**

Currently, with every request, a session of TensorFlow is getting started; loading the computation graph in memory; computing prediction on a test image and giving the response.

So I tried to keep **the session open by defining the graph and session globally.**
The idea is I want the computation graph to be loaded in memory(from the frozen inference graph (.pb file)) and, with every incoming request, it should give the output instead of loading the computational graph every time with the incoming request and in that way time for each execution will be less thus decreasing the latency. **(correct me if I am wrong)**

While the code is **working for the first time**, from 2nd time this is giving me **Attempted to use a closed Session** error. I am **not using** TensorFlow servings.
My code is somewhat like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
global detection_graph, session
def init():
    global detection_graph, session
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
        with tf.io.gfile.GFile(model_path, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# In some other package
def method(session, detection_graph, filename, PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGE):
    with session:
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = session.run(
            [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

# Remaining code...
```

**Note:**   I found this answer [How to keep tensorflow session open between predictions? Loading from SavedModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701902/how-to-keep-tensorflow-session-open-between-predictions-loading-from-savedmodel) but it did not solve my issue.