# unable to use Trained Tensorflow model

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am new to Deep Learning and Tensorflow. I retrained a pretrained tensorflow  *inceptionv3* model as *saved_model.pb* to recognize different type of images but when I tried to use the fie with below code.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("tensorflow/trained/saved_model.pb",'rb') as  f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        tf.Graph.as_graph_def()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        g_in=tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
        LOGDIR='/log'
        train_writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
        train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

it gives me this error -

```
 File "testing.py", line 7, in <module>
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I tried many solution I can find for this problem and modules in *tensorflow/python/tools* which uses the *graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())* function are giving me same error. Please tell me how to solve this or tell me the way in which I can avoid  *ParseFromString(f.read())* function. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Please use the **frozen_inference_graph.pb** to load the model,
than to use the saved_model.pb

```
Model_output
- saved_model
  - saved_model.pb
- checkpoint
- frozen_inference_graph.pb     # Main model 
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.meta
- pipeline.config
```

Comment: This was actually my problem! Thank you!

Comment: I am getting the same error. Still unable to do, could you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439124/google-protobuf-message-decodeerror-error-parsing-message-with-type-tensorflow

Comment: @Naga kiran: There is no such a thing (```frozen_inference_graph.pb```) inside the folder ```TensorFlow/workspace/training_demo/exported-models/my_model/```. Only the ```saved_model.pb```. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that you saved your trained model using **[`tf.saved_model.Builder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/Builder)** provided by **TensorFlow**, in which case you could possibly do something like:

### Load model

```
export_path = './path/to/saved_model.pb'

# We start a session using a temporary fresh Graph
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    '''
    You can provide 'tags' when saving a model,
    in my case I provided, 'serve' tag 
    '''

    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], export_path)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    # print your graph's ops, if needed
    print(graph.get_operations())

    '''
    In my case, I named my input and output tensors as
    input:0 and output:0 respectively
    ''' 
    y_pred = sess.run('output:0', feed_dict={'input:0': X_test})
```

To give some more context here, this is how I saved my model which can be loaded as above.

### Save model

```
x = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
y = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('output:0')

export_path = './models/'
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
signature = tf.saved_model.predict_signature_def(
                inputs={'input': x}, outputs={'output': y}
                )

# using custom tag instead of: tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING]
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=obj.sess,
                                     tags=['serve'],
                                     signature_def_map={'predict': signature})
builder.save()
```

This will save your protobuf ('saved_model.pb') in the said folder ('models' here) which can then be loaded as stated above.

Answer (score 5):

Have you passed as_text=False when saving a model? Please have a look at: [TF save/restore graph fails at tf.GraphDef.ParseFromString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351760/tf-save-restore-graph-fails-at-tf-graphdef-parsefromstring)