# How to Fix: "google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message" when creating tensorflow text summary

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow, coreml, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to run a script to get a text summary out of a tensorflow .pb model such as this:

```
    OPS counts:
    Squeeze : 1
    Softmax : 1
    BiasAdd : 1
    Placeholder : 1
    AvgPool : 1
    Reshape : 2
    ConcatV2 : 9
    MaxPool : 13
    Sub : 57
    Rsqrt : 57
    Relu : 57
    Conv2D : 58
    Add : 114
    Mul : 114
    Identity : 231
    Const : 298
```

I am overall trying to convert a .pb model to a .coremlmodel and am following this article:

https://hackernoon.com/integrating-tensorflow-model-in-an-ios-app-cecf30b9068d

Getting a text summary from the .pb model is a step towards that. The code I try to run to create the text summary follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.framework import graph_pb2
import time
import operator
import sys

def inspect(model_pb, output_txt_file):
    graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
    with open(model_pb, "rb") as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

    sess = tf.Session()
    OPS = sess.graph.get_operations()

    ops_dict = {}

    sys.stdout = open(output_txt_file, 'w')
    for i, op in enumerate(OPS):
            print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        print("{}: op name = {}, op type = ( {} ), inputs = {}, outputs = {}".format(i, op.name, op.type, ", ".join([x.name for x in op.inputs]), ", ".join([x.name for x in op.outputs])))
        print('@input shapes:')
        for x in op.inputs:
            print("name = {} : {}".format(x.name, x.get_shape()))
        print('@output shapes:')
        for x in op.outputs:
            print("name = {} : {}".format(x.name, x.get_shape()))
        if op.type in ops_dict:
            ops_dict[op.type] += 1
        else:
            ops_dict[op.type] = 1

    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
sorted_ops_count = sorted(ops_dict.items(),     key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    print('OPS counts:')
    for i in sorted_ops_count:
        print("{} : {}".format(i[0], i[1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
"""
Write a summary of the frozen TF graph to a text file.
Summary includes op name, type, input and output names and shapes. 

Arguments
----------
- path to the frozen .pb graph
- path to the output .txt file where the summary is written

Usage
----------
python inspect_pb.py frozen.pb text_file.txt

"""
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    raise ValueError("Script expects two arguments. " +
          "Usage: python inspect_pb.py /path/to/the/frozen.pb /path/to/the/output/text/file.txt")
inspect(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

I ran this command:

```
 python inspect_pb.py /Users/nikhil.c/Desktop/tensorflowModel.pb   text_summary.txt
```

But instead of receiving the expected output, I receive this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "inspect_pb.py", line 58, in <module>
        inspect(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
      File "inspect_pb.py", line 10, in inspect
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

and do not really know where to start. Other similar questions that seem to receive the same error message do not make too much sense. What do I do?

Comment: To add on, I tried this with an example model from the website and it worked perfectly, so I believe it might have to do with the actual model. Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: It's possible that your model is created with an incompatible version of TensorFlow, or that it is damaged somehow. Could you share the actual model file somewhere?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5HyYBIWhF413y1G9ki4FKcMoFWzWscR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that is the .pb model. I downloaded from google firebase following this article:

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/deploy

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work with TF 1.14. What version of TF did you create this model with?

Comment: I downloaded it from google automl, and I believe they use the latest version of TensorFlow.

Comment: Is there any way to be able to convert it to coreml?

Comment: I stuck with the same kind of problem, unable to solve it! Can anybody help me ? Here is the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439124/google-protobuf-message-decodeerror-error-parsing-message-with-type-tensorflow

Answer (score 5):

According to this [tensorflow/moonlight issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/moonlight/issues/56), there are 3 critical components:

- TensorBoard
- Protocol Buffer aka Protobuf (a replacement of XML and JSON file transfer for better performance and protect corruption of data - via some kind of hashing, thus the parsing decode error)
- Bazel

I can reproduce the issue from a GCP (cloud) v.1.14 platform to a local TensorFlow (JitTeam Docker) v.1.13 - If I retrain a model it works, if I import, all scripts crash on this error.

You have [other export options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117938/unable-to-use-trained-tensorflow-model/55981972#55981972) assuming you still have access to the original file and system

You can try to [install other components](https://jkjung-avt.github.io/build-tensorflow-2.0.0/) version with this guide - The author recommend to use his scripts instead of pip3 install. (you can read comments for review of the scripts). It is based on official Tensorflow builds.

You can also try

```
pip3 install protobuf==3.6.0
```

This is related into tensorflow issue #21719

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
with gfile.GFile(frozen_graph, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read(-1)) 
    # the -1 returns the contents of the file as a string
```

I saw it in the documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile#read